# Snowflake view privileges

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two Snowflake databases/schemas: database.schema.A and database.schema.B.  Database.schema.A has its own user - UserA.  I need to create or replace a view in database.schema.B using UserA's privileges.  UserA can perform select, insert, and deletes on tables in database.schema.B but not on the view in database.schema.B.
Shouldn't UserA be able to create or replace the view in database.schema.B if UserA has full/all privileges?  If not, is there another way for UserA to drop and recreate the view when updated records are available?

Answer (score 0):

UserA can create or replace view in database.schema.B provided if UserA has privileges to create views in that database. Grant UserA privileges and can update the views.

Comment: I verified UsetA had privileges to create views on my database.B shema but still get an insufficient privileged to operate on view message.

Comment: UserA should have usage privileges on database B and it's related schema. Try providing GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE as well as SCHEMA to UserA.

Answer (score 0):

Users cannot be assigned privileges in Snowflake, only *roles* can. Assuming that you mean RoleA and RoleB rather than UserA and UserB then:

- If RoleB created the view `database.schema.B` then only RoleB (the "owner"), or a role that contains it as a member (higher in the role hierarchy), can drop or replace it. Even if you provide all privileges to another role, it won't be able to drop it.
- Users can assume different roles. If you log in with UserA it can assume RoleB if it needs to perform drop/replace operations that RoleB has ownership of. Of course, this means you need to assign UserA to RoleB.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I granted privileges to roleA to create views on database.B.  Is there a different permission I need to grant to assign RoleA to RoleB?

Comment: Have a look at the `grant` documentation linked below to understand how to grant one role to another: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-role.html

Answer (score 0):

The role that has OWNERSHIP permission on the view is the role who can recreate/drop the view.  This is the same for any object.

Additionally, the role will need to need USAGE on the view's database/schema AND access to the underlying data (e.g., if the view is created off a table, they need access to the table including USAGE on database and schema for the table).